# Send User and Password of Spring security in Ajax (jquery) with basic authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a webservice which requires a basic authentication to access it. Then I have a Web Service Client, which is in spring (mvc, security, etc). From the client application, I make an ajax request (jquery) to my webservice, the query is basically as follows:

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index1.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
  },
  data: '{ "comment" }',
  success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
  }
});
```

For this I have to expose the text of the username and password. For both applications I drive the same users. my question is, is there a way to intercept the request and put the values ​​of username and password of the spring session security ?. This in order not to expose the password in the javascript file, but at the same time to send the authentication webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new endpoint on the server (as you said that it is already Spring, MVC etc) that is hosting the page, POST the page to that end point and then at that endpoint you could set the authorization headers and do the actual call onto the web service. Get the response and send the same back to the page or handle it on the server. However you seem fit for your needs.

- Page -- POST to --> Server
- Server adds Auth headers.
- Server GET's to WebService endpoint
- Server will get response and send the response back to Page.

Here your server where the page is hosted is acting as a filter setting the credentials for you.